# Orbeon form builder visibility xpath

Tags: xpath, orbeon

I'm trying to make control with name "control-3" to be visible if another checkbox control with name "control-4"(data type is boolean) is checked. Can anyone help me?

P.S. I think something fundamentally wrong in this framework UX if developer with solid experience cant create the simple visibility xpath even reading the documentation in 20 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XPath expression:

`$control-4 = true()`